Differential form exact on connected set
I'm having trouble with the following proof:
Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a connected open set, and let $\omega$ be a continuous differential 1-form on $U$. Suppose that $\int_\phi \omega = \int_\psi \omega$ whenever $\psi$ and $\phi$ have the same start and end points. Show that there exists a $C^1$ function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega = df$.
So far I have employed the fact that $U$ is path-connected to define $\gamma: [0,1] \to U$ such that $\gamma(0) = p_0$ and $\gamma(1) = p$ where $p_0$ is a fixed point in $U$ and $p$ is a variable point in $U$. I then defined $f(p) := \int_\gamma \omega$ and know I want to use the FTC, but am unsure how exactly to get the desired result.

Please proofread and make this legible.

Fixed it. Thank you!

Great. Next step: Explicitly calculate $df$, i.e., the partial derivatives. I recommend you work it out with $n=2$ so that you won’t get lost in notation.

Is this the right track? $df_p(v) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(p+tv) - f(p)}{t} = \frac{\int_{\gamma_{tv}} \omega}{t}$. I want to show that this equals $\omega_p(v)$, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I specifically told you to calculate partial derivatives. You will need to use  path independence explicitly.

I don't understand how you get the partial derivatives from this. Doesn't path independence just guarantee that $f(p)$ is well-defined?

Write down the definitions of the partial derivatives of $ \int_{p_0}^p\omega$.
